# Swift cast if possible

Tags: swift

I have this code

```
     let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any?]
            if var first = jsonData[0] as! String?{
                if(first=="Error"){
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.postNotFoundLabel.isHidden = false
                    });
                }else if(first=="Empty"){
                    print("Empty")
                }
            }
```

What i want to do is to cast `jsonData[0]` to String if it's possible and if it's not then move on.But instead when it's not possible application stops and gives me an error

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1092054d8) to 'NSString' (0x108644508).
```

How can i cast only when it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to force-cast to an optional String. That's not what you want.

Change:

```
if var first = jsonData[0] as! String? {
```

to:

```
if var first = jsonData[0] as? String {
```

This tries to cast to String. If `jsonData[0]` isn't actually a String, you get `nil` and the `if var` fails.

And you probably want `if let`, not `if var` since you don't seem to be making any change to `first`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all JSON objects will **never** return optional values so `[Any?]` is nonsense.

Second of all the error message says the type cast to **string** is inappropriate because the type of the result is actually a **dictionary**.

Solution: Check the type for both `String` and `Dictionary`

```
if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [Any],
   let first = jsonData.first {
      if let firstIsDictionary = first as? [String:Any] {
        // handle case dictionary
      } else if let firstIsString = first as? String {
        // handle case string
      }
   }
```

PS: A type cast *forced unwrap optional to optional* (`as! String?`) is nonsense, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `as!` if you are not sure that casting will succeed. The exclamation mark after the `as` keyword forces the casting, which throws an error if the casting does not succeed.

Use `as?` instead, which returns an optional variable of the type you were trying to casting to. If the casting fails, instead of throwing an error, it just returns nil.

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [Any]
    if var first = jsonData.first as? String{
        if(first=="Error"){
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.postNotFoundLabel.isHidden = false
            });
        }else if(first=="Empty"){
            print("Empty")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swifty way to do what you're doing :)

```
guard  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any?], let first = jsonData[0] as? String else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.postNotFoundLabel.isHidden = false
    });
    return
}
if(first == "Empty") {
    print(first)
}
```